# PermissionError when copying files, renaming them and saving to a new location

Tags: python

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rLRHm.png)Hey guys! The file has all premisions and i cant fidure out what is the problem. I did try both shutil.copyfile and shutil.copy

ples help

Hey guys! The file has all premisions and i cant fidure out what is the problem. I did try both shutil.copyfile and shutil.copy

ples help

Answer (score 1):

`original_file_path` seems not to be a file path, but a path to a directory. The error doesn't make it too clear, but `shutil.copyfile()` only works on files and will throw a `PermissionError`. Try `shutil.copytree()`; from the docs:

> Recursively copy an entire directory tree rooted at src to a directory named dst and return the destination directory